# Pentaho reporting excel output

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

Is there a way to generate data in multiple excel sheets once the data exceeds the sheet limit in pentaho report designer?
we are dealing with huge data and we need the data to be generated in different sheets once the sheet limit exceeds.

Thanks

Comment: What I found xlsx support more than 10 lac rows in a sheet. I think this is not possible using Pentaho report designer. But if your data belong to only raw data then you can easily implemented (create excel report) this using Pentaho data integration.

Comment: will check PDI ... Thanks